# Achieve letter-spacing in RaphaelJs

Tags: raphael, letter-spacing

Is there a way to set letter-spacing in raphael js text? It can be done easily in CSS, how can  I do it in raphael? Any hacks would also do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with normal css. take a look here : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html . The css is applied to svg too.
Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FzaH3/) that shows svg text with `letter-spacing`.

Comment: @rohan_vg That is because firefox has not supported the svg letter-spacing attribute for the last 10 years: see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371787.

Answer (score 2):

`Paper.print()` has a letter-spacing attribute:

```
var txt = r.print(10, 50, "O HAI", r.getFont("Comic Sans"), 30, 'middle', 1).attr({fill: "#fff"});
                                                                          ^
                                                           this is the letter spacing
```

See the **[docs on that](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.print)**.

Note that this needs "cufon-style" font files to be included and will render a non-selectable path object instead of real text.